# Install ubuntu 22.04 bootloader in windows boot manager partition

Tags: windows, 22.04, bootloader

I purchased a dell laptop with windows 11 on it. I am in the middle of installing Ubuntu 22.04.1. I have reached the part of the install, where I'm ready to install the software. I'm at the point where it is, asking me to install the device for bootloader installation. It has defaulted to /dev/nvme0n1 EDILOCA EN605 1TB. Selecting the drop down from the device for bootloader installation, it displays several partitions to install the boot loader program on. One of them is the Windows Boot Manager. Is there any issue with me changing from /dev/nvme0n1 to the Windows Boot Manager partition /dev/nvme0n1p1? I do not want to blow away my windows 11 installation.

What's gratitude for any and all help!

Comment: The Windows Boot loader is for Windows and only Windows. When you started the install from the Live Media were you not at some point in the install asked to install along side Windows?

Comment: Installing grub into a Windows NTFS partition can cause issues. If you are installing in UEFI boot mode, it may not matter what you select. Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs in UEFI mode to first drive's ESP - efi system partition. And new Windows 11 systems do not have the CSM/legacy/BIOS boot mode.